# Mute Audio for Certain Duration

Tags: c#, naudio, mute

I want to mute my Audio for certain duration, let's say after 2 seconds from it's start till 4 seconds of it's play duration, that is for 2 seconds.

I want to do this for 50 different Audios with different start and stop times for Muting. Currently, I am using two `System.Timer` class's objects with interval of 1st being Start time and of second being stop time for Muting and I have 50 `if` clauses to check for the 50 Audios and set their start and stop timer accordingly like this:

```
    //50 checks

    AudioFileReader ar;
    Timer start_timer = new Timer(),stop_timer=new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ar = new AudioFileReader(@"D:\SampleDegradedSpeech.wav");

        var a = new WaveOut();

        a.Init(ar);

        a.Play();

        start_timer.Interval = //start time;
        stop_timer.Interval = //stop time;

        start_timer.Tick += t1_Tick;
        start_timer.Start();

        stop_timer.Tick+=t2_Tick;
        stop_timer.Start();
    }

    private void t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ar.Volume = 1;
        stop_timer.Stop();
    }

    private void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ar.Volume = 0;
        start_timer.Stop();
    }
```

Is there any other/better way of doing it?
Any replacements for the two timers?
Something like `ar.mute(start,stop)`?

Comment: Wait, do you seriously have 50 separate audio players? And 50 separate if blocks? Or am I totally misunderstanding?

Comment: I am currently creating a new object of AudioFileReader class for every audio like this:
     var obj=new AudioFileReader(string track);

this track is coming as parameter input to my method.
And currently it is 50 switch cases because I don't know if switch case is better and efficient or Array creation, in terms of memory consumption and time consumption.
Sorry I'm a newbie :(

Comment: No, it's not wrong, and it wasn't a criticism, I just honestly can't imagine a situation in which I'd need 50 audio clips playing simultaneously. It's late, but I'll try and see if I can take a look at this tomorrow if no one else has gotten to it.

Comment: it's not simultaneously. It's one after another.
I think it will be better if i store start and stop time in a database and then access them.

Comment: Okay, so what you really want is to play X (where X = 50 here) audio clips in a row, like a playlist?

Comment: No Furkle. I want to play 5 random audios from 50. I am able to do that. I want to know which is the best way to store the start and stop duration of mute. 
Eg audio 1 has mute start time at 2 second and stop at 4 second
Audio 2 has mute time at 6s and stop at 8s
so on and so forth till:
Audio 50 has mute time at 9s and stop at 11s
how and where should i store my start and stop values for faster,better,less memory consuming and efficient working of my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own implementation of an `IWaveProvider` that wraps your `WaveSource` to set the sample bytes to 0 in the `Read` method when the underlying stream reached that point in time. You stop changing the byte array when you reached the end of the mute period.

A simple implementation of this is this `MutingReader`:

```
private class MutingReader : IWaveProvider
{
    private TimeSpan _start;
    private TimeSpan _end;
    private WaveStream _stream;

    // constructor
    public MutingReader(WaveStream stream, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _start = start;
        _end = end;
    }  

    // gets called each time the WaveOut needs more bytes
    public int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(_stream.CurrentTime);
        var samples = _stream.Read(array, offset, count);
        // if we are between our Start and End Time stamps
        if (_stream.CurrentTime > _start &&
            _stream.CurrentTime < _end)
        {
            // silence by only returning zeroes in the array
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                array[i + offset] = 0;
            }
        }
        return samples;
    }

    #region IWaveProvider Members
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return _stream.WaveFormat; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You can use above implementation as follows:

```
var wo = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent();
var reader = new MutingReader(
        new WaveFileReader( @"v1.wav"),
        new TimeSpan(0,0,2),  // mute after 2 seconds
        new TimeSpan(0,0,4)); // unmute after 4 seconds
wo.Init(reader);
wo.Play();
```